# Убрать тень FAB при нажатии на Api < 21

Tags: android, android-layout

Здравствуйте.
[image: Момент нажатия]
Необходимо убрать тень от FAB, которая появляется при нажатии на FAB. На Api > 21 это убирается `fab.setStateListAnimator(null)`.
Как убрать тень клика для Api < 21;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30614090/4829111

Comment: нужно убрать тень, которая появляется при нажитии (исправил вопрос, извините)

Answer (score 2):

```
ViewCompat.setElevation(fab, 0f);
```

Hack trick!

Comment: Прошу прощения за то, что не до конца выразил вопрос.  Нужно убрать тень, которая появляется в результате клика